# Qt Editing Custom Data Structures

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to utilize the Model/View architecture to accomplish my goal but I am unsure as to whether this is the proper tool to use for this task.

I have a Material System I have been using, which I more recently have created an editor for using Qt, it uses a `QGraphicsView` to display items which are interconnected to form a final fragment shader code, this works extremely well however, I am having difficulties finding a way to display these custom data structures without hand coding widgets for each type of item.

These custom data structures are simply classes with members which I wish to modify using an interface depending on each members type. For instance if the item is a `Value` which in my material system represents a single variable, like a texture, I would like to be able to have 2 editable areas, one for the texture's path on disk, and one for the name of the variable.

What is the best approach for interpreting custom structures like this and creating widgets based on their type, and then mapping those widgets to edit/display them. All the google searching I found led me to the `Model/View` architecture however it seems this is more made for things like SQL databases and XML files.

```
class Value
{
  std::string  m_strType, m_strName, m_strValue, m_strLocation; 
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more details on the custom data structures?

Comment: Here is a really simple class with some things renamed and getter/setter methods removed, this holds all the info needed for a GLSL texture sampler in my material system, is it possible for Qt to handle something like this or is the view system made to handle mostly lists of things, or databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like the [Property Browser Framework](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html). In short, you'll make all of the members you want to edit [properties](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.3/properties.html), and then use the property browser framework to create a model that you can then attach a view to.